Duplicate class co.touchlab.stately.collections.FunctionsKt
I want to update KamelMedia library into the latest version, but I receive this error on build:
Duplicate class co.touchlab.stately.collections.FunctionsKt found in modules stately-collections-jvm-2.0.0-rc3 (co.touchlab:stately-collections-jvm:2.0.0-rc3) and stately-iso-collections-jvm-2.0.5 (co.touchlab:stately-iso-collections-jvm:2.0.5)
I'm using kotlin multiplatform project and I'm using stately library also in other module but.
I tried to exclude
implementation("media.kamel:kamel-image:0.9.2") {
   exclude(
      group = "co.touchlab",
      module = "stately-collections-jvm" <-- this library I'm using in the different module
   )
}

Has anyone encountered this problem and knows how to fix it?
